# API Test Automation Framework Structure

Tags: python, api, automation, web-api-testing

I am planning to have API Automation Framework built on the top pf Python + Request Library

**Expected flow:**

1) Read Request Specification From input file "csv/xml"

2) Make API Request & get Response & analyse the same

3) Store Test Results

4) Communicate the same

Initial 'smoke test' to be performed with basic cases then the detailed ones.There will be 'n' number of api's with respective cases.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you asking for help, or asking if something like this already exists? Specific to the Python, there is a library that extends the Request library called requests_runscope. So, everything in your code would be exactly the same; however, the storing of the results, measuring performance/latency are taken care of for you, with a swell UI as well.  See: https://www.runscope.com/docs/code-examples/python  (disclaimer: I work for Runscope)

Comment: You could also consider using [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to achieve the same sort of test framework.  This might be simpler than trying to build your own.

Comment: Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I have done API Automation framework using JAVA - TestNG - HTTP Client.

It's a Hybrid framework consist of,

1. Data Driven Model : Reads data from JSON/ XML file.
2. Method-Driven : I have written POJO for JSON Objects and Arrays reading and writing.
3. Report : I will be getting the Report using TestNG customized report format
4. Dependency Management: I have used Maven.
5. This framework I have Integrated with Jenkins for Continous Integration.
6. SCM : I have Used GIT for that.